# Array Decimal Index was outside the bounds of the array - C#

Tags: c#, array, decimal

> El error que me sale es: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException has been thrown

Aqui muestro el codigo:

```
        Double[] NumAlea = new Double[10];
    Double[] Array = {0.03991, 0.38555, 0.17546, 0.32643, 0.69572, 0.24122, 0.61196, 0.30532, 0.03788, 0.48228};

    int m = 0;
    int p = 0;

    int Apuesta = ApI;
    int op = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=Array.Length; i++)
    {
        op++;
        Console.WriteLine("#{0} Operancion", op);

       
        if (Array[i] <= .5){}
```

**En donde me da el error es en el if Array[i] ya intente cambiar el tamaño del array pero no me funciono**

Comment: Primer punto los arrays no pueden cambiar de tamaño una vez creados, segundo punto estas intentando iterar desde la posicion 0 hasta la longitud del arreglo <-- esto siempre te va dar index out of array exception pork los arreglo empiezan en 0 entonces si la longitud es 3, solo va tener indices 0,1,2  y el 3 estara fueral del tamaño,  la condicion del for debe ser `<` no `<=`

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se soluciona quitando el = en la condición del for

**Solución:**

```
        Double[] NumAlea = new Double[10];
        Double[] Array = { 0.03991, 0.38555, 0.17546, 0.32643, 0.69572, 0.24122, 0.61196, 0.30532, 0.03788, 0.48228 };

        int m = 0;
        int p = 0;

        int Apuesta = ApI;
        int op = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            op++;
            Console.WriteLine("#{0} Operancion", op);


            if (Array[i] <= .5) { }
        }
```

Esto se debe a que tu array tiene un `lenght` de 10 y un array empieza guardando valores desde el índice 0, lo que significa tu ultimo índice en 9

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falla en la última iteración del bucle for. Debes de quitar el igual en la condicion del for. Ya que el array tiene 10 elementos y tu lo recorres 11 veces. Array[10] no existe.

for(int i=0; i<Array.Length; i++)